# Constructor is not valid because parameter cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, catel

Here goes another one.

I have two ViewModels: `MainViewModel` and `ConnectionViewModel`
And two views: `MainWindow` and `ConnectionView`

The automatic binding works wonder and each view model goes to its view.
The problem is that `ConnectionViewModel` takes a `Connection` model parameter in its constructor. So when it's time for it to be instanciated, I get this message in the output window (thanks to the logger):

***Constructor is not valid because parameter 'connection' cannot be resolved from the dependency resolver***

```
public ConnectionViewModel(Connection connection, IMessageService messageService, IAnotherService anotherService)
```

Hence getting a null `Connection` inside `ConnectionViewModel`.

I probably missed a (few) step(s). Isn't the model supposed to be created with the viewmodel? Do I have to instanciate it beforehand, and if yes, where? Or do I have to register it first?

Comment: and what about the codes ?

Comment: Try to make the Connection as a public Property and make the affectation just after the instanciation.

Comment: I don't see what code is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand what I missed.

The usage of nested UserControls is originally about lists; with this point of view, it makes sense for your parent ViewModel to contain a collection property of a model.

Since I had only one `Connection`, and not a list, and wanted to separate everything cleanly, I didn't think about putting a `Connection` in my `MainViewModel`, but you still have to **bind a property as a UserControl's DataContext in XAML**.

I had `<views:ConnectionView />` in my MainWindow.xaml, and virtually nothing in `MainViewModel`.

What I needed was to have a `Connection` property in MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel(IMessageService)
    {
        Connection = new Connection();
    }

    public Connection Connection
    {
        get { return GetValue<Connection>(ConnectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConnectionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData ConnectionProperty = RegisterProperty("Connection", typeof(Connection));
    /*...*/
}
```

and a binding in the xaml:

`<views:ConnectionView DataContext="{Binding Connection}"/>`